# how to convert string data:application/octet-stream;base64 to data:image/(png, jpeg...);base64 to display image

Tags: javascript, base64, fingerprint

Goodnight

I need your help. I have a string like this "data: application / octet-stream; base64, ...." result of sample capture from digital person web application SDK 3 and want to convert this string to "data: image / png; base64, ... "just to show the captured fingerprint. I don't want to save or load a file, I need after the capture display the finger image. I can easily send the wsq data to be processed to the server side

Comment: if the data is in fact a PNG, then a simple `.replace('application/octet-stream', 'image/png')` - then you can use the resulting string as the `src` for an `<img>`

Comment: The probem is that "Data" contains a lot of information: "Data":"{
"Compression":2,
"Data":"here Byte base 64",
// Base64url encoded image
"Format":{
"iHeight":403,
"iWidth":200,
"iXdpi":508,
"iYdpi":508,
"uBPP":8,
"uDataType":1,
"uImageType":2,
"uPadding":2,
"uPlanes":1,
"uPolarity":2,
"uRGBcolorRepresentation":0,
"uSignificantBpp":8},
"Header":{
"DeviceId":1407938095516745728,
"DeviceType":49264417346420736,
"iDataAcquisitionProgress":100,
"uDataType":1
},
"Version":1
}" And this information is a only byte  "data:application/octet-stream;base64, HERE IS THE BYTE"

Comment: More information page 51  Digital Persona SDK Deleper guide v3

Comment: You're going to need to clarify your question if you want an answer. @JaromandaX is correct on the face of things, but your question is missing a lot of information